# Insert Google Adsense code in Ionic breaks display

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, adsense

In this simple [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/EmmanuelGleizer/pen/rVOLme), I have a bar and a slider. Works fine, but if I add the Google Adsense code, then display is broken. How should I insert the Adsense code to display the Ad at the top of the web page.

What I mean by "display is broken": the bar overlays the start of the ion-content (hello1 hello2). I already put **class="has-header"** in the *<ion-content>*.

NB I use Ionic framework both for the mobile site, and (next step) for the hybrid app. I don't expect the ad to work in the native code. I just need to display the Adsense ad on the mobile web site.
Code of the ad is:

```
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- hybride_320x50 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-4134311660880303"
     data-ad-slot="1861097476"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Skeleton of the ionic page:

1. header / angularjs
2. Google ad
3. bar
4. ion-content

   41. content
   42. slider
   43. content

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend you to use AdMob. I've written this native plugin which supports ionic: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps. Moreover it will also let you show interstitials.

`ionic plugin add cordova-admob`

```
<script src="lib/angular-admob/angular-admob.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule']);

app.config(['admobSvcProvider', function (admobSvcProvider) {
  // Optionally you can configure the options here:
  admobSvcProvider.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",
    autoShowBanner:       true,
    autoShowInterstitial: true
  });
}]);


app.run(['admobSvc', function (admobSvc) {
  admobSvc.createBannerView();
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();


  // Handle events:
  $rootScope.$on(admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
    console.log('adOpened: type of ad:' + e.adType);
  });
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, does it support inline ads (between the content itself)? For example show ads in the middle of a list, or repeat ads after certain number of items in a list?

Comment: @pewpewlasers sorry not, this is discouraged by admob: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287 and it could even cause your app to be rejected as considered against policy in some cases if they mimic/overlap the content of the app.

Answer (score 0):

one fast solution is add the following class to your style

```
.adsbygoogle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Absolute position will make Ad overlays the 1st element of the page, in my case the bar. I need to put the Ad in it's own block div on top of page, and below (not under) the ad goes the Bar.

Comment: Therefore add a top padding to your ion-nav-views

Comment: thx for the idea but it doesnt seems to work: http://codepen.io/EmmanuelGleizer/pen/ZGpGvJ I guess this is because bar is not an element of  ion-view but a sibling to it.